# Проверка на заполненность массива с помощью bool

Tags: c++

Добрый вечер! Мне для учёбы нужно написать программу-архив, имеющую шаблон-структуру, по которому заполняется массив. Т.е. струтура содержит вопросы анкеты, а в массиве,в зависимости от его размерности, будет находиться такое количество заполненных анкет. По заданию нужно ещё написать функцию, **стирающую** все данные из массива. Нам сказали добавить в шаблон структур переменную типа `bool`, которая Ноль, если эл-т пустой и Единица, если эл-т заполнен. Т.е. обнуляя `bool`, мы должны обнулить и содержимое массива. Однако у меня так не выходит. Компьютер не чувствует связи между значением переменной `bool` и заполненностью массива. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка и как её исправить? Всё откомментировано, надеюсь, разобраться будет несложно. Спасибо огромное зарание за помощь!!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

typedef struct
{ 
  char name[7];
  int zach;
  bool FR;
} anketa;
FILE *fp;

      anketa mas[1];

void vvod(int, int); //----------- функция ввода
void read_ff(int);   
void delet (int, int);//---------- функция очистки!
int print_1(int);  
int print_all(int);  
int poisk_f(int, int);

    int main()
{     setlocale( LC_ALL,"Russian" ); 
      setlocale( LC_ALL," ");
      char sim;
      int i=0;
      int kol;
       printf("Maximalnoe kol-vo anket?"); //---------кол-во анкет; размерность массива
       scanf("%d", &kol);
       for(int j=0; j<kol; j++)
       { mas[j].FR=0;  //-----------------показываем,что когда массив пуст, FR равна нулю
       }
       printf("i=%d", i);
      for(;;)
      {
       printf("\n\4to budem delat??\n");
       printf("v - vvod dannyh. Dobavit' odnu novuyu anketu ; \n");
       printf("r - 4tenie. Vyvesti na ekran odnu anketu ; \n");  
       printf("R - vyvesti vse ankety ; \n");  
       printf("F - naity anketu ; \n"); 
       printf("d - udalit vse ankety\n"); //--------------------ф-я меню Удалить
       sim = getch(); if(sim=='\n') sim = getch();

       if (sim=='v')  
         {
          vvod(i, kol);
          i++;
         } 
       if (sim=='r') 
       {printf ("\vvedite index elementa kotoryi hotite nape4atat");
         scanf("%d", &i);
          print_1(i-1);

       }  // -------распечатать
       if (sim=='R') 
          {printf ("\n Vash Arhiv:\n");
           print_all(kol); 
          }
       if (sim=='F') 
          { 
            poisk_f(i, kol);
          }
         if (sim=='d') 
          { delet(i, kol);  //--------------ВЫЗЫВАЕМ ФУНКЦИЮ УДАЛИТЬ!!
          }

        if((sim!='R')&&(sim!='d')&&(sim!='r')&&(sim!='v'))
         {printf ("VVEDITE 4to-to drugoe\n");
         }  
      }

      system("PAUSE");
      return 0;

}

//************ввод данных,заполнение одной анкеты-********

void vvod(int i, int kol)
{      printf("i=%d, kol=%d", i, kol);
               {
       if ((i<kol)&&(mas[i].FR!=1))  // ---------заполняем только тогда,когда индекс не превышает размерность и FR!=1             
      { printf ("\neiy? ");
       scanf("%s", &mas[i].name);
       printf ("\niiia? ca??oee?  ");
       scanf ("%d", &mas[i].zach); 
       fprintf(fp, "%s ", mas[i].name);
       fprintf(fp, "%d \n", mas[i].zach);
      read_ff(i);
       fclose(fp);
       mas[i].FR=1; //----------------заполнив одну анкету, приваиваем её FR начение 1, показывающее, что она заполнена
       i++;
                   }
                else printf("\niao ianoa aey caiene. Auaa?eoa a?oao? iia?aoe?!\n ");

}

// ********************удаление. функция очистки*******************
void delet (int i, int kol)
{ for(i=0; i<kol; i++)
     {mas[i].FR=0;  //------------для всего массива делаем FR=0
     }
}

void read_ff(int i)
{

     fp=fopen("k.txt", "r");
      for (i=0; i<3; i++)
     { 
       fscanf (fp, "%s", &mas[i].name);
       fscanf (fp, "%d", &mas[i].zach);
     }
      fclose(fp);
}

int print_1(int k)
{    
     printf("eiy:   %s, ", mas[k].name);
       printf("ca??oea:   %d \n", mas[k].zach);

}

int print_all(int m)
{  for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
      { print_1(i);
      }
}

int poisk_f (int j, int kol)
{ char n[7];
  printf("aaaaeoa eiy ?aeiaaea, aieaoo eioi?iai oioeoa iaeoe ");
  scanf("%s", n);
  for(j=0; j<kol; j++)
  {if (strstr(mas[j].name,n)!=NULL)
  { print_1(j);
  }
    else 
    {printf ("ia iaeaaii ie iaiie caiene");
     break;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: В следующий раз код вставляйте на pastebin :-) с ипапка, честно, никакого желания качать нет.

Comment: Код добавлен в вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз речь идет о C++, то для начала стоит заменить C-массив `mas` на `std::vector<anketa>`, размерность которого значительно проще менять вызовами `resize()`, и не будет предпосылок к утечкам памяти в будущем.

Далее, в функции vvod() есть такие строки:

```
       fclose(fp);
       mas[i].FR=1; //Этот флаг не сохраняется  в файл!!!
```

Получается, что флаг признака заполненности никогда не выводится в файл. Да и вообще, т.к. файл открывается и закрывается только внутри функции `read_ff`, то запись в него где-либо в других частях программы лишена смысла.

Кстати, **НИГДЕ** в программе на запись этот файл не открывается! Так что архив всегда будет пустым.

---

Посмотрев внимательно понимаешь, что легче все переписать с нуля, чем реанимировать этот код. И перейти от С все же к C++.

Answer (score 2):

Что бросается в глаза - это объявление `anketa mas[1];`, т.е ваш массив всегда содержит **1 элемент**, что бы вы не делали дальше.

Нужно либо **ограничить количество анкет сверху**, т.е написать что-то в духе `anketa mas[MAX_COUNT];`, либо **выделять память динамически:** `anketa* mas = (anketa*)malloc(kol * sizeof(anketa)`. После этого память освобождается с помощью `free(mas);`

---

*Правда, вопрос у вас имеет тэг `С++`, поэтому напишу еще и выделение памяти в стиле `C++`: `anketa* mas = new anketa[kol];`, а далее - `delete[] mas`.*

При попытке поиска других возможных ошибок, честно говоря, у меня глаза в трубочку свернулись, поэтому допускаю, что это не единственная проблема данного кода.